# slick.js controls not working when autoplay and fade turned on

Tags: slick.js

I am using slick.js carousel on my website and everything is fine except one thing I can’t get working. When `autoplay` and `fade` are turned on, the controls (dots and arrows) don’t react on click. (The autoplay just goes on and on). When I set either of the two to `false` the controls work fine. What am I missing?

This is my setup:

```
 $('#slider').slick({
            dots: true,
            fade: true,
            autoplay: true,
            autoplaySpeed: 2000,
            slidesToShow: 1,
            slidesToScroll: 1,
            pauseOnHover: false
        });
```

Comment: Please add a JSFiddle so we can check the error

Answer (score -2):

try `focusOnSelect: true`, it worked for me.